# How atomic the fork() syscall actually is?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

Assuming `check_if_pid_exists(pid)` returns true when a process with such a *pid* exists (but possibly hasn't been running yet) or false when there is no process with such *pid*, is there any chance in parent code for a race condition when the `fork()` returned the child *pid*, however the kernel hasn't had a chance to initialize the data structures so that `check_if_pid_exists(child)` returns false? Or perhaps after returning from `fork()` we have a guarantee that `check_if_pid_exists(pid)` returns true?

```
pid_t child = fork();

if (child == 0) {
  /* here the child just busy waits */
  for (;;)
    ;
}

if (child > 0) {
  /* here the parent checks whether child PID already exists */
  check_if_pid_exists(child);
}
```

Comment: If an external event kills the child really quickly (for instance a systemtap script monitoring forks), `check_if_pid_exists(child)` may return false.

Comment: Correct, thanks. However assuming that no "third party" agent kills our processes?

Comment: It could be killed by a first party, like a resource limit

Comment: I think since the kernel is designed to accommodate the case where the first two instructions the parent makes after the fork invoke a `wait` syscall, the kernel has almost certainly set up the child completely by the time fork returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The `fork()` returns after the new task is created and visible as expected by the parent. Most everything wouldn't work otherwise.

Whether the process has had a chance to run at all or has started quite a bit, is not known at that point. Whether the child has completed is known as you receive the `SIGCHLD` signal once that happens.

Where you can have a race is with the `SIGCHLD` if not handled properly. That is, you are expected to ignore the `SIGCHLD` signal, call `fork()`, save the results appropriately so you have the PID of the child (i.e. allocate a struct to save the child `pid_t` value), then use one of the `wait()` functions to know whether the child died.

Assuming your `fork()`ed process is expected to run *for a while*, then the

```
check_if_pid_exists(child) == true
```

will likely be true 99.9999% of the time (actually, assuming the parent is in control of when the child is expected to exit, make it 100% of the time).

As mentioned by others, many things can prevent the new process from running:

- Not enough memory
- You already started too many children
- The child tries to do something and encounters a fatal error and exits
- Some third party *thing* prevents the `fork()`
- ...

Also, `fork()` may return -1 in case it fails to create the child.

However, if the question was about: how do I track the lifetime of a child? Then the correct answer is for the parent to check whether it died. You should not rely on a function such as `check_if_pid_exists()` searching for the process under `/proc/...` or similar implementation (see [`waitid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitid)), because such a function may determine that the process is still running, then the process dies, and yet the function still returns true...

```
// ignore SIGCHLD
struct sigaction sa, chld;
sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sa.sa_flags = 0;
__sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);

[...]

int child_is_running = 0;

[...]

pid_t child = fork();
if(child == 0) ...do stuff in the child...

if(child < 0) ...handle error...

int child_is_running = 1;

[...]

wait(...);

if(...child exited...) child_is_running = 0;
```

Now you can write a safe `check_if_pid_exists()`:

```
int check_if_pid_exists()
{
    return child_is_running;
}
```

In my example here, I only allow one child. If you need multiple, that's where you need a better scheme (probably a struct to save the child info and a table of some sort or linked list of all your children).